# Sort command not working as expected?

Tags: shell, sorting

I have got a dataset like this

```
tack2@domain.com,2009-11-27
overflow@domain2.com,2009-11-27
overflow@domain2.com,2009-11-27
```

When I am running command to delete all of the same entries of column2

```
sort -t ',' -k2 stars.txt -u
```

It is deleting the entry of column1, and in order to delete the duplicate entries of column2, I am having to enter `-k3` flag

```
sort -t ',' -k3 stars.txt -u
```

Can anyone explain to me why it is happening? Why I have to enter +1 to the column in the file to delete the column?

Comment: Can you show the output you're getting for the `-k2` and the `-k3` cases?  And maybe you should identify the O/S that you're using, too.  It pretty much has to be GNU `sort` you're using; classical Unix systems don't allow the interleaving of file names and options as you're doing.  The `-k3` notation finds no column 3, so it treats all the rows as identical.

Answer (score 2):

In my system all works correctly:

```
$ sort -t, -k1 -u 1.txt 
overflow@domain2.com,2009-11-27
tack2@domain.com,2009-11-27

$ sort -t, -k2 -u 1.txt 
tack2@domain.com,2009-11-27
```

It may be due to your locale.
Can you please repleat the command but with LANG=C?

```
$ LANG=C sort -t, -k1 -u 1.txt 
$ LANG=C sort -t, -k2 -u 1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

this is typical awk job, no sorting needed. I add one short line here, in case you want to give it a try.

```
awk -F, '!a[$2]++' file
```

will do the job.